# to get the sub-string which has common starting word and ending word in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a log file where I want to get the sub-string which start with `<fullpath>"` and ends with `"`. For Example:

> Member ID=":LtWeek2:1133548" fullPath="Time.Latest Weekly : FOLDER.Latest 52 Weeks Ending 04-21-13.Week Ending 02-24-13" levelName="LtWeek2" rpmSetOperator="Add"/Member ID=":LtWeek2:1168692" fullPath="Time.Latest Weekly : FOLDER.Latest 52 Weeks Ending 04-21-13.Week Ending 02-24-13" levelName="LtWeek2" rpmSetOperator="Add"/Member ID=":LtWeek2:1191834" fullPath="Time.Latest Weekly : FOLDER.Latest 52 Weeks Ending 04-21-13.Week Ending 03-10-13" levelName="LtWeek2" rpmSetOperator="Add"

Say, the above data will be present in "A1".

Now I have to write a code such that only strings such as

> fullPath="Time.Latest Weekly : FOLDER.Latest 52 Weeks Ending 04-21-13.Week Ending 02-24-13"
>   fullPath="Time.Latest Weekly : FOLDER.Latest 52 Weeks Ending 04-21-13.Week Ending 02-24-13"
>   fullPath="Time.Latest Weekly : FOLDER.Latest 52 Weeks Ending 04-21-13.Week Ending 03-10-13"

So what I thought is, having a starting word as "fullPath" and ending word as "levelName", if we can able to get the text in between means, my problem can be solved.

Above approach is just from my side, any other methods/approach is also fine.

Comment: Oh, now I see. Is that entire body of characters a single string in, say, cell A1?  (I've deleted my answer for now, since it was clearly off-base).

Comment: Yeah...before the MemberId was stated with <MemberID, so it was not displayed it seems. now i deleted that in the prob statement.

Comment: Please see corrected code. Forgot result array was transposed. Now writes result to range "B1:D1").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code reads the string in cell A1 of Sheet1, extracts the substrings of interest, and writes them back to the worksheet in columns B, C & D.

```
  Sub ExtractFromLog()
      Dim str As String
      Dim entries() As String
      Dim numEntries As Long
      Dim i As Long
      Dim startPos As Long
      Dim endPos As Long

      str = Sheet1.Range("A1").Value
      numEntries = (Len(str) - Len(Replace(str, "fullPath", ""))) / Len("fullPath")
      ReDim entries(1 To numEntries)

      startPos = 1
      For i = 1 To numEntries
          startPos = InStr(startPos, str, "fullPath")
          endPos = InStr(startPos + 1, str, "levelName") - 1
          entries(i) = Mid(str, startPos, endPos - startPos + 1)
          startPos = endPos + 1
      Next i
      Sheet1.Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(1, i)) = entries
  End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry Sir, its not happening, i'm just getting a "=" in the cell where i'm trying to paste ur above formulae.

Comment: Do you by any chance have an extra space character or two at the beginning of the formula when you paste it in? After I highlight and copy the formula, it is working OK when I paste it in to Excel.

Comment: Thanks Chuff...! This code is working fine, but what the solution i need is not yet reached. This code will print the first greped text in between fullPath and levelname for as many times as the it en-counters these two key words.

Comment: Please be so kind as to accept my answer (the checkmark) if it worked out for you. Thanks and welcome to StackOverflow!